# Writing bounded subset as countable union of disjoint intervals

Tags: real-analysis

I consider a bounded subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ and want to know if $A$ can be written as a countable union of disjoint intervals (open or half open)?

In case that is true: Does it mean that a bounded subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ can have no more than countable many points of discontinuity (holes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cantor set is a bounded set of $\Bbb R$ which can not be expressed as a countable disjoint union of open intervals.